# How do we tell our currently running year of age?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

I'm wondering how to tell other people that I have completed 20 years of my life and I'm about to turn 21 in a few months. 
My guesses are:

◆ My 21st year is currently running.

◆My 21st year is going on.

◆ I am running 21st year.

◆ I'm pursuing the 21st year.

I know these sentences sound awkward. I just want to know how native speakers say this in conversations.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but, haven't you already stated that in your question? The expression *I'm about to turn 21* says so.

Comment: @Ustanak I'm curious to know the continuous form like "currently running" or so.

Comment: The continuous for it's just *I'm turning 21*.

Comment: @Ustanak It should be like: "My 21st year is going on." Is it correct?

Comment: Both "My 21st year is going on" and "My 21st year is currently running" sound unidiomatic to me. "I am running 21st year." sounds as if you were trying to say that you have been involved in athletics for 21 years, but in an ungrammatical way. The proposed suggestions with "turning/am about to turn" are far better. Or simply: I'm 20 years old.

Answer (score 6):

In practice people normally just say *I'm 20*.

If you specifically wanted to mention ***21*** (because it sounds like a more "important" number, perhaps), the idiomatic standard is *I'm **in my 21st year*** (which you can reasonably say at *any* point between your 20th and 21st birthday), but it's a bit pretentious/poetic for most contexts unless "facetious".

If you specifically wanted to convey that you're nearer to 21 than 20 (i.e. - your 21st birthday is less than 6 months away), you can say *I'm 20 **going on** 21*.

To convey that your 21st birthday is *imminent*, you can say *I'm **almost / nearly / just under** 21*.

You can say *I'll **turn** 21 next month* or *I'll **be turning** 21 next month*, but you'd rarely be in a context where you could use the "true" *continuous*. For example, *How old are you? I'm turning 21* would be a rather strange thing to say. The only context where that would seem natural to me is if the speaker doesn't know exactly when the relevant birthday occurs *I haven't seen your son for years - surely he must be turning 21 by now*.